# How to check if items in collection contains a specific value?

Tags: c#, linq

I've a collection called `AvailableNations`, in this I've a property called `IsSelected`, I need to check after the first item, if all items have the `IsSelected` value setted to true, I did this:

```
var allChecked = lsVm.AvailableNations.Skip(1).Where(c => c.IsChecked == true).Any();
```

but this will return `true` in any case, instead should return false 'cause I've almost one item with a property setted to `false`.

Maybe is `.Any()` the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `All()` here, it will check that all items are checked :

```
var allChecked = lsVm.AvailableNations.Skip(1).All(c => c.IsChecked);
```

Comment: and you don't need the ``==true`` in your where, its like checking ``true == true``

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: if someone needs to append `==true` or `==false` it often indicates that he should rename variables. In this case it's clear that it's a `bool` and `All(c => c.IsChecked)` is very readable.

Comment: If there is only one item in the collection this will return true since `All() ` returns `true` for the empty collection (first item skipped) Is this the intended behavior?

Comment: @schmelter it often indicates tha the bool is actually nullable in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

`Any` method (in this context) returns true when *any* of the `AvailableNotations` is checked. What you need is `All` extension method.

```
var allChecked = lsVm.AvailableNations
                    .Skip(1)                // Skip first element
                    .All(x=>x.IsChecked );  // returns true when `IsChecked` is true for all, else false.
```